# segue work only at the second click instead of one click

Tags: ios, swift, segue

am working on a to do list app and when am testing the app the segue work only at the second click for the first time 
then the segue start to work at the first click with late in the print ln statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved
instead of writing this:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

I wrote this:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, did**De**selectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```